# Django: Duplicating object in database

Tags: django, transactions, mutex, concurrent-programming, python-decorators

I'm having some issues with transaction management. I created a simple scenario where my problem happens. There follows my view function:

```
@permission_required('person.create')
@distributedlock
@commit_on_success
def view(request, name):
    obj = get_object_or_none(Person, name=name)
    if obj is None:
        obj = Person(name=name)
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponse('Object created successfully.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Object already exists.')
```

Where `@distributedlock` is a distributed mutex to prevent two processes from executing at the same time. My goal is to prevent duplicated objects.

The problem is that I'm getting duplicated objects, i.e., two `Person` objects with same name and it just happens in concurrent requests.

I guess `@permission_required` is creating a transaction and then the request gets locked on `@distributedlock`. When it resumes then, in fact, the object doesn't exists in that transaction.

I did a workaround switching `@permission_required` with `@distributedlock`, but I guess it cannot be my permanent solution, since it makes sense to check for permissions before locking. (I'm not sure if it really solves my problem. I did it and now I'm just monitoring)

Can anyone help me? Is my hypothesis right?

Comment: Making the Name unique is no solution?

Comment: It is just a simplified scenario. There is no way to have a database constraint.

Comment: It looks like I'm right. The problem didn't happen again and I'm still looking a definite fix instead of this workaround. I'm still very surprised that Django creates a transaction for any query (even if I don't update anything).